# I have trouble in SearchView Google Maps

Tags: java, android, maps, searchview

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                String location = searchView.getQuery().toString();
                //List<Address> addressList = new ArrayList<>();
                List<Address> addressList = null;
                if(location != null || !location.equals("")){
                    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
                    try{
                        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location,1);


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Address address = addressList.get(0);
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude());

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location));
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,10));
                }
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

It's working on AVD Emulator but not working on my phone. I searching something and crash have error "

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.coffeebakeryfordriver, PID: 27228
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
> at com.example.coffeebakeryfordriver.MapsActivity$2.onQueryTextSubmit(MapsActivity.java:96)
> at android.widget.SearchView.onSubmitQuery(SearchView.java:1301)
> at android.widget.SearchView.access$1000(SearchView.java:101)
> at android.widget.SearchView$7.onEditorAction(SearchView.java:1278)
> at android.widget.TextView.onEditorAction(TextView.java:7042)
> at com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection.performEditorAction(EditableInputConnection.java:138)
> at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:357)
> at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:89)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7551)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
> I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 27228 SIG: 9

"

Comment: addressList  is empty add all funtion into try

Comment: No not yet. I tried to build on SS Snapdragon okay not problem, but building on Xiaomi Mediatek not working

Answer (score 0):

use this method below in your class and call the method inside at onReadyMap() method , this work with me fine .

```
private void searchMethod(){

    // adding on query listener for our search view.
    binding.idSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            // on below line we are getting the
            // location name from search view.
            String location = binding.idSearchView.getQuery().toString();

            // below line is to create a list of address
            // where we will store the list of all address.
            List<Address> addressList = null;

            // checking if the entered location is null or not.
            if (location != null || location.equals("")) {
                // on below line we are creating and initializing a geo coder.
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this);
                try {
                    // on below line we are getting location from the
                    // location name and adding that location to address list.
                    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // on below line we are getting the location
                // from our list a first position.
                Address address = addressList.get(0);

                // on below line we are creating a variable for our location
                // where we will add our locations latitude and longitude.
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

                // on below line we are adding marker to that position.
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location));

                // below line is to animate camera to that position.
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));
            }
            return false;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```